# Mails aren't sent

Tags: emails, 9

I'm simply trying to send a mail with the following code.

```php
function contact_form_mail($key, &$message, $params){
    switch ($key) {
        case 'contact':
            // Set headers etc
            // $message['headers']['Reply-To'] = $params['to'];
            $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html';
            $message['headers']['From'] = $params['from'];
            $message['to'] = $params['to'];
            $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
            $message['body'] = $params['body'];
        break;
    }
}

public function sendForm(){
        $user = $this->getCurrentUser();
        $recipent = $this->findEmailForLocation($this->getLocation());
        if(empty($recipent)){ return; }
        $request = \Drupal::request();
        $subject = $request->get('subject');
        $body = $request->get('body');
        if(empty($subject) || empty($body)){
            return $this->redirect('contact_form.contact', ['error' => 'Fill in all fields.']);
        }
        $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
        $mailManager->mail(
            'contact_form',
            'contact',
            ['test@test.com'],
            $user->getPreferredLangcode(),
            ['to' => [$recipent], 'from' => $user->getEmail(), 'subject' => $subject, 'body' => $body],
            $user->getEmail(),
            TRUE
        );
        return $this->redirect('contact_form.contact', ['success' => 'Data sent']);
    }
```

I'm getting this error.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManager->doMail() (line 286 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Mail/MailManager.php).

I have no clue which value is wrong and/or what kind of datatype it should be.

Comment: Best thing to do is go look in the code at the error being mentioned (line 286 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Mail/MailManager.php). That's about the $message['body'] so it's likely your `$body = $request->get('body');` isn't an array as it's expecting

Comment: I don't think you need this line (I've never needed to do this), and it could potentially be the source of your issue: `            ['to' => [$recipent], 'from' => $user->getEmail(), 'subject' => $subject, 'body' => $body],`

Comment: @Leigh it took me a while to find out yeah. For some reason they want the body to be an array. Not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for answers for a while I figured out that `body` needs to be an array instead of a string. Not sure why. But I changed it, and it directly started working.

Comment: It's documented in [`hook_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_mail/9.3.x): ***body**: An array of lines containing the message to be sent.*

Comment: Yeah I think I just overlooked it